# Configuration about eclipse + Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I wrote a little helloworld jsp file to test it. But it failed. I can't figure it out.Any one help me ?

I got these error info:

HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /myjsp/WEB-INF/myjsptest.jsp. Reason:

```
NOT_FOUND
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTTP error 404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) means that the requested resource was not found by the server.

The problem doesn't seem to be related to Tomcat or Eclipse but rather to your web application. I think the reason is that you are trying to access a JSP file in `WEB-INF` folder. You shouldn't do that because `WEB-INF` folder is not accessible directly from a web browser. Your JSP files should be outside of it.

`WEB-INF` folder is used to store configuration files (e.g. `web.xml`) and Java classes (e.g. servlets). JSP files and all static content should be placed outside of it.

You may find more information about JSP technology e.g. in [this tutorial](http://www.jsptutorial.net/) or [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/index.html) (in Chapter 12).

Comment: JSP files in WEB-INF are however accessible by `RequestDispatcher` in a servlet and by `<jsp:include>` in another (public accessible) JSP. This effectively prevents JSP files which require preloading of the data by a servlet or are supposed to be part of some template from being directly accessed. See also [servlets tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).